# Handling API calls with async/await in React Native

Tags: react-native, async-await, ecmascript-2017

I want to have a separate file for API calls -

`APIHandler.js`

```
const loginAPI = 'https://..../login';

export async function login(emailAddress, pass) {
    const reqOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({

            email: emailAddress,
            password: pass,

        })
    };

    let response = await fetch(loginAPI, reqOptions);
    return response;
}
```

Now in my `login.js`, I want to do so:

```
onLoginPressed = async () => {
    let response = login(this.state.email, this.state.password)

    if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
       //Login success
    } else {
        //Login error
    }
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work. After I press login, nothing happens. Can anyone tell me where I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `login` is an async function, and you want to wait for the response to be returned *from `login`*, you have to `await` the call to `login` too:

```
let response = await login(this.state.email, this.state.password)
```

`login` itself awaits for the fetch call to finish. So for you to wait for `login` to finish, you must await it. If you don't, `login` returns a promise, which as you observed, is not the response object from the request.